# Changing the font for menu in the Windows Forms application, .net3.5

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, fonts

I have a menu on my form that is defined as follows:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu mainMenu1;

//Then

private void InitializeComponent()
{
 this.mainMenu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu(this.components);
 this.Menu = this.mainMenu1;
}
```

I set the font for the entire form, but the Menu items still ignore it. How do I make the font bigger for the Menu items? I can't find Font property for the Menu or MenuItem....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it directly if you're using a `MainMenu`. You should be using a [`MenuStrip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead.

If you absolutely must use `MainMenu`, you have to set the [`OwnerDraw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.ownerdraw(v=vs.90).aspx) property of the `MenuItem` to `true` and override/implement the [`DrawItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.drawitem%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [`MeasureItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.measureitem%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) events so that you can manually paint it.

---

Here's a very basic custom menu item class; it's by no means complete or fully functional, but it should get you started:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

class CustomMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    private Font _font;
    public Font Font
    {
        get
        {
            return _font;
        }
        set
        {
            _font = value;
        }
    }

    public CustomMenuItem()
    {
        this.OwnerDraw = true;
        this.Font = SystemFonts.DefaultFont;
    }

    public CustomMenuItem(string text)
        : this()
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }

    // ... Add other constructor overrides as needed

    protected override void OnMeasureItem(MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // I would've used a Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle) here instead,
        // but for some reason I always get an OutOfMemoryException,
        // so I've fallen back to TextRenderer

        var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Text, this.Font);
        e.ItemWidth = (int)size.Width;
        e.ItemHeight = (int)size.Height;
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Blue, e.Bounds);
    }
}
```

Here's a 3-deep test usage:

```
MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
MenuItem menuFile = new CustomMenuItem("File");
MenuItem menuOpen = new CustomMenuItem("Open");
MenuItem menuNew = new CustomMenuItem("New");

public MenuTestForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Menu = mainMenu;
    mainMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuFile);
    menuFile.MenuItems.Add(menuOpen);
    menuOpen.MenuItems.Add(menuNew);
}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, does this need to be done for every MenuItemm in MainMenu?

Comment: I think you have to register the event for each `MenuItem`, but you don't necessarily need to write a different method for each one. A better approach would be to derive your own class from `MenuItem`, give it a `Font` property and override the two events in there.

Comment: spoke too soon. I have few items that are children of MainMenu and after setting the font to bigger, they no longer show up. I suspect that I need to override the MeasureItem after all. What do I put inside the event?

Comment: Actually, even after the binding the event to each MenuItem doesn't work because customItem.Text (where MenuItem customItem = (MenuItem)sender;)  is always outputting the text I assiged to the very top item even when the child menu item is drawn. I have 3 level menu in total. Isn't there an easier way of doing it? I can't really spend the time on re-writing the whole menu bit. It's just a style change and should be fairly simple to do.

Comment: Updated my answer. When it comes to using obsolete controls, there's no free lunches when you need custom behaviour :P